# show one div content and in other div

Tags: jquery, html

My question is about HTMl and Jquery.

i have two divs, `Div 1` and `Div 2`. Div 1 have some content.

i use js to get one div content and showed it in other div. But it showing undefined error.

```
if (activeIndex == 1) {
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log("i am here");
            var shippingAdrres = document.getElementsByClassName('billing-address-details').innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('shipping-address-after-summary').innerHTML = shippingAdrres;

           });

        }
```

errro:

http://prntscr.com/nd235u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might as well fully use jQuery:

```
if (activeIndex == 1) {
        $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log("i am here");
        var shippingAdrres = $('.billing-address-details').html();
        $('#shipping-address-after-summary').html(shippingAdrres);

       });

    }
```

More Info about .html() here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Check if this $('.billing-address-details').length gives your more then a value of 0 (Just execute it in the console). If it's 0 then your shipping address field is not found. Maybe you have a typo in your class-selector (or the class)

Comment: Here is a working jsfiddle with your code (I only added the activeIndex variable at the start): https://jsfiddle.net/dmx4o1sz/1/ - Sorry for the delay, got distracted for a while

Answer (score 0):

**document.getElementsByClassName** will return you an array so you have to select it using index.

```
if (activeIndex == 1) {
            $( document ).ready(function() {
            console.log("i am here");
            var shippingAdrres = document.getElementsByClassName('billing-address-details')[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('shipping-address-after-summary').innerHTML = shippingAdrres;

       });

    }
```

Comment: i got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

> document.getElementsByClassName('billing-address-details')

returns an array so you cannot call innerHTML on that, thus it returns `undefined`

try at least:
`document.getElementsByClassName('billing-address-details')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: i got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: well, check first, whether `document.getElementsByClassName('billing-address-details')` returns non-empty array, then use `[0]` to select first element of the array (hopefully, the desired element if your selector is right), only then you can use `innerHTML`